# Cassandra: 'Date' datatype is intruduced in v.2.2.0, not earlier

Tags: datetime, types, cassandra, date

> date is introduced in Cassandra 2.2.0. You are currently using Cassandra 2.1.12

I have to use v. 2.1.12, which data type is better for a **birthday** column (date_of_birth), then? Since, the **Date** data type is unknown in this version, and I just need the date, not date-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the date-time and disregard the time component when you insert or use the results (0 it up).
that way you get basically a Date component, takes a little more space but sorting and everything else goes smoothly and as you would expect.